# Assigning to dask series using positional indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have two DataFrames, df1 and df2, that share an index.  I would like to assign the values in df1 based on a value in df2.

The standard pandas code looks like this:

```
df1['column1'][df2['column2']==i] = j
```

This populates df1 correctly when run on all the inputs.

However, the same syntax on dask DataFrames returns an error:

> TypeError: 'Series' object does not support item assignment

`dd.where()` and `dd.mask()` don't seem to work as they return the original value as well.

Is there a dask equivalent to the above pandas code?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do your task, you should:

- use *mask* to get the new column,
- save it back to *column1*.

To test, I used the following source DataFrames:

df1:

```
   column1  xxx
0        1  230
1        2  160
2        3  160
3        4  190
4        5  190
5        6  260
6        7  260
7        8  260
8        9  300
```

df2:

```
   column2  yyy
0       11  402
1       12  349
2       13  336
3       14  369
4       15  402
5       16  209
6       17  492
7       18  455
8       19  387
```

Then I set variables:

```
i = 15
j = 100
```

I created both *Dask* DataFrames as follows:

```
dd1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, chunksize=5)
dd2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, chunksize=5)
```

And to do the actual processing, I ran:

```
dd1.column1 = dd1.column1.mask(dd2['column2'] == i, j)
result = dd1.compute()
```

The result is:

```
   column1  xxx
0        1  230
1        2  160
2        3  160
3        4  190
4      100  190
5        6  260
6        7  260
7        8  260
8        9  300
```

So, value in *df1.column1* for index == 4 (where in *df2.column2* == *15* (*i*))
has been set to *100* (*j*).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for the dask.dataframe.Series.where method.  It seems to work ok for me.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.where

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: import dask.dataframe as dd                                             

In [3]: s = pd.Series(range(5))                                                 

In [4]: ds = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions=2)                                   

In [5]: ds.where(ds > 1, 10).compute()                                          
Out[5]: 
0    10
1    10
2     2
3     3
4     4
dtype: int64
```